# Question posted on multiple stackexchange website?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

So I have this question, but it's good for more than just 1 website. Is it allowed / good to post the question on the websites where I feel it should be on? My question for example: ["ESRI.ArcGIS.DataSourcesGDB.FileGDBWorkspaceFactoryClass" cannot be embedded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20239479/esri-arcgis-datasourcesgdb-filegdbworkspacefactoryclass-cannot-be-embedded)

It is a C# question but also a gis question. So it should belong on and could be usefull for either https://gis.stackexchange.com/ and https://stackoverflow.com/ . 
**So should I post it on both?**